# How do I not render ViewChild element but access it in the parent component instead?

Tags: javascript, angular, viewchild

I have a component that I'm using like this in a different component:

```
<inline-help>
            <help-title>{{::'lang.whatIsThis'|i18n}}</help-title>
            <help-body i18n="lang.helpBody"></help-body>
</inline-help>
```

In `inline-help` I'm using @ViewChild and ng-content to display the `help-title` and `help-body`.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'inline-help',
    template: `
<div class="inline-help">
    <div class="help-icon">
        <i class="en-icon-help"></i>
    </div>
    <div #helptext class="inline-help-text text-left">
<ng-content select="help-title"></ng-content>       
<ng-content select="help-body"></ng-content>
    </div>
</div>`
})

export class InlineHelpComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    @Input() fixed: boolean;
    @ViewChild('helptext', {static: false}) text: ElementRef;
......
```

What I want to do is create a new component like `<inline-help-content>` that I can use as such inside :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'inline-help',
    template: `
<div class="inline-help">
    <div class="help-icon">
        <i class="en-icon-help"></i>
    </div>
    <inline-help-content [helpTitle]="something" [helpBody]="something"></inline-help-content>
</div>`
})
```

But I **DONT** want to change all the instances of

```
<inline-help>
            <help-title>{{::'lang.whatIsThis'|i18n}}</help-title>
            <help-body i18n="lang.helpBody"></help-body>
</inline-help>
```

that I use in other parts of the codebase, since that's a lot. Is it possible to parse the ViewChild and then get the text inside it and call another component to with the texts as inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `InlineHelpComponent` template, you can wrap the `<ng-content>`s in elements with template reference variables assigned to them:

```html
<div #helpTitle><ng-content select="help-title"></ng-content></div>
<div #helpBody><ng-content select="help-body"></ng-content></div>
```

Those template reference variables give you access to the native elements, so you can then pass the `innerText` properties of those elements into your new `InlineHelpContentComponent` (just be sure to hide the projected content in `InlineHelpComponent` so it doesn't display twice). Here's what the `InlineHelpComponent` template would look like:

```html
<div class="inline-help">
  <div style="display:none;">
    <div #helpTitle><ng-content select="help-title"></ng-content></div>
    <div #helpBody><ng-content select="help-body"></ng-content></div>
  </div>
  <inline-help-content
    *ngIf="showInlineHelpContent"
    [helpTitle]="helpTitle.innerText"
    [helpBody]="helpBody.innerText">
  </inline-help-content>
</div>
```

[Here's a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pass-projected-content-into-child-component) demonstrating this approach.

I found I had to include that `*ngIf="showInlineHelpContent"` on the `inline-help-content` component, and set the flag in `ngAfterContentInit` after a `setTimeout`, otherwise I was getting an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error.